# Why do I get a `permission denied` when trying to include a generated .env file in a Makefile target?

Tags: makefile

I have a need to reload an environment file in a target. So i tried a simple example that generates an env file and tries to load it in a target. The error i get is a permission denied error. I already tried to set `chmod +r` for the env file but this does not solve the problem. So i am wondering why i get the `permission denied error`? The file is actually created but not included.

```
ENV_FILE := .env

.PHONY: create-env-file
create-env-file:
    @echo "Generating environment file... $(ENV_FILE)"
    @echo "VAR1=1" > $(ENV_FILE)
    @echo "VAR2=2" >> $(ENV_FILE)

.PHONY: load-env-file
load-env-file:
    echo "- Reloading env file..."
    $(MAKE) create-env-file
    chmod +r $(ENV_FILE)
    include $(ENV_FILE)

.PHONY: start
start: load-env-file
    echo $(VAR2)
```

Output running

```
$make start
echo "- Reloading env file..."
- Reloading env file...
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make create-env-file
Generating environment file... .env
chmod +r .env
include .env
make: include: Permission denied
make: *** [load-env-file] Error 1
```

Comment: What's `include`? The error hints at missing execute permissions on `include`, not the env file.

Comment: Makefile newbie but I read this and got the impression that it should work. 
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html

So my understanding was that I could use `include` to include a generated env file like this.

Answer (score 0):

The `include` statement of GNU `make` is an instruction to `make`.  It cannot be used inside a recipe, where every line is interpreted as a command to be executed by the shell.  You get a permission denied error because the shell finds an `include` somewhere in your executable search path, but cannot execute it as a command.

Possibly that's because you have `.` in your path (generally a bad idea) and a directory named `include` in your project folder.  I can reproduce your "Permission denied" error under these circumstances, but I get a "Command not found" instead if there is no `include` in my `PATH`.

You talk about an `.env` file as if that's a thing, but it is not a *`make`* thing or a standard *shell* thing.  You  appear to intend it for defining `make` variables or shell variables, but it's unclear which.  Your use of `include` suggests the former, but the name seems more appropriate for the latter.  And if you really did mean it for `make` variables, then why not just put the variable definitions directly in the makefile?

Docker makes use of `.env` files, so maybe that's what you're thinking of, but (i) it would be totally inappropriate to load the contents of a Docker `.env` file as `make` or shell variables, and (ii) it would be suspicious to generate the contents of such a file via `make`.

In any case, **if you want `make` to build a file for you then make that file a target of a rule.**  And if you really do want to `include` that file into your makefile, then creating a normal rule for the file, combined with putting the `include` directive in the right place, will take care of the whole issue.  Example:

```
include .env

all:
        @echo 'VAR1: $(VAR1)'
        @echo 'VAR2: $(VAR2)'

.env:
        @echo "Generating environment file $@ ..."
        @echo "VAR1=1" > '$@'
        @echo "VAR2=2" >> '$@'
```

That works because `make` attempts to re-make the makefile and all its dependencies before it does anything else.

Lastly, do note that if that really is what you want to do then `.env` or any other name beginning with a period (`.`) is a *terrible* name for the purpose.  Instead, choose almost anything that's not going to be omitted from directory listings by default.